# type mismatch using sparse_precision_at_k from tensorflow.metrics

Tags: tensorflow

I am working with a toy example to check how `tensorflow.metrics.sparse_precision_at_k` works

From the documentation:

> labels: `int64` `Tensor` or `SparseTensor` with shape
>       [D1, ... DN, num_labels] or [D1, ... DN], where the latter implies
>       num_labels=1. N >= 1 and num_labels is the number of target classes for
>       the associated prediction. Commonly, N=1 and `labels` has shape
>       [batch_size, num_labels]. [D1, ... DN] must match `predictions`. Values
>       should be in range [0, num_classes), where num_classes is the last
>       dimension of `predictions`. Values outside this range are ignored.
>
> predictions: Float `Tensor` with shape [D1, ... DN, num_classes] where
>       N >= 1. Commonly, N=1 and predictions has shape [batch size, num_classes].
>       The final dimension contains the logit values for each class. [D1, ... DN]
>       must match `labels`.
>
> k: Integer, k for @k metric.

So I have written a following example accordingly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

pred = np.asarray([[.8,.1,.1,.1],[.2,.9,.9,.9]]).T
print(pred.shape)

segm = [0,1,1,1]
segm = np.asarray(segm, np.float32)
print(segm.shape)

segm_tf = tf.Variable(segm, np.int64)
pred_tf = tf.Variable(pred, np.float32)

print("segm_tf", segm_tf.shape)
print("pred_tf", pred_tf.shape)

prec,_ = tf.metrics.sparse_precision_at_k(segm_tf, pred_tf, 1, class_id=1)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.variables_initializer([prec, segm_tf, pred_tf])
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c6243802dedc> in <module>()
     25 print("pred_tf", pred_tf.shape)
     26 
---> 27 prec,_ = tf.metrics.sparse_precision_at_k(segm_tf, pred_tf, 1, class_id=1)
     28 sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
     29 tf.variables_initializer([prec, segm_tf, pred_tf])

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py in sparse_precision_at_k(labels, predictions, k, class_id, weights, metrics_collections, updates_collections, name)
   2828         metrics_collections=metrics_collections,
   2829         updates_collections=updates_collections,
-> 2830         name=scope)
   2831 
   2832 

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py in _sparse_precision_at_top_k(labels, predictions_idx, k, class_id, weights, metrics_collections, updates_collections, name)
   2726     tp, tp_update = _streaming_sparse_true_positive_at_k(
   2727         predictions_idx=top_k_idx, labels=labels, k=k, class_id=class_id,
-> 2728         weights=weights)
   2729     fp, fp_update = _streaming_sparse_false_positive_at_k(
   2730         predictions_idx=top_k_idx, labels=labels, k=k, class_id=class_id,

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py in _streaming_sparse_true_positive_at_k(labels, predictions_idx, k, class_id, weights, name)
   1743     tp = _sparse_true_positive_at_k(
   1744         predictions_idx=predictions_idx, labels=labels, class_id=class_id,
-> 1745         weights=weights)
   1746     batch_total_tp = math_ops.to_double(math_ops.reduce_sum(tp))
   1747 

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py in _sparse_true_positive_at_k(labels, predictions_idx, class_id, weights, name)
   1689       name, 'true_positives', (predictions_idx, labels, weights)):
   1690     labels, predictions_idx = _maybe_select_class_id(
-> 1691         labels, predictions_idx, class_id)
   1692     tp = sets.set_size(sets.set_intersection(predictions_idx, labels))
   1693     tp = math_ops.to_double(tp)

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py in _maybe_select_class_id(labels, predictions_idx, selected_id)
   1651   if selected_id is None:
   1652     return labels, predictions_idx
-> 1653   return (_select_class_id(labels, selected_id),
   1654           _select_class_id(predictions_idx, selected_id))
   1655 

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py in _select_class_id(ids, selected_id)
   1627   filled_selected_id = array_ops.fill(
   1628       filled_selected_id_shape, math_ops.to_int64(selected_id))
-> 1629   result = sets.set_intersection(filled_selected_id, ids)
   1630   return sparse_tensor.SparseTensor(
   1631       indices=result.indices, values=result.values, dense_shape=ids_shape)

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sets_impl.py in set_intersection(a, b, validate_indices)
    191     intersections.
    192   """
--> 193   a, b, _ = _convert_to_tensors_or_sparse_tensors(a, b)
    194   return _set_operation(a, b, "intersection", validate_indices)
    195 

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sets_impl.py in _convert_to_tensors_or_sparse_tensors(a, b)
     82   b = sparse_tensor.convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor(b, name="b")
     83   if b.dtype.base_dtype != a.dtype.base_dtype:
---> 84     raise TypeError("Types don't match, %s vs %s." % (a.dtype, b.dtype))
     85   if (isinstance(a, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor) and
     86       not isinstance(b, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor)):

TypeError: Types don't match, <dtype: 'int64'> vs <dtype: 'float32'>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example of using this metric.

```
sess = tf.Session()
predictions = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]],
                          dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.constant([3, 2], tf.int64)
precision_op, update_op = tf.metrics.sparse_precision_at_k(
       labels=labels,                                          
       predictions=predictions,
       k=1,
       class_id=3)
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(update_op))
```

This examples prints 0.5 because our predictions predicted class 3 for all (two) examples and only one of them is correct.

The two returned ops (`precision_op` and `update_op`) can be confusing. Please read this guide -https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.metrics. It talks about "streaming" metrics, but the same logic applies to all metrics. Basically, `update_op` actually updates the variables using the examples/labels you gave and `precision_op` is idempotent - it simply returns the current value of the metric. If you never call `update_op` the current value of the metric is undefined, likely `nan`.

In regard to your code, the shapes are not correct. In the simplest case, labels should just give the correct label for each example in the batch. In your case, there are just two examples, so there should be just two labels. Also, you don't need to create variables yourself - `sparse_precision_at_k` does it for you.